# Increasing Parentheses Size in Combinations

Tags: brackets

How do you make the parentheses size of combination brackets larger?

I used the code

```
    \dbinom{\floor*{\dfrac{x}{2}}}{2}
```

and the result was [image: my result]
but the parentheses weren't tall enough to cover the whole combination. Is there any way to get the parentheses to fit the height of the combination; to get the parentheses covering the floor function too? Or is this normal?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a minimal compilable example?

Comment: You get a much better result anyway with `\dbinom{\floor{x/2}}{2}`. As a rule, one should avoid stacked fractions in (generalized) fractions whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}
    \[\dbinom{\floor*{\dfrac{x}{2}}}{2}\]
    \[\left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \floor*{\dfrac{x}{2}}\\2
    \end{array}\right)\]
\end{document}
```